# Как распаковать 7z архив запакованный в винде?

Tags: bash, 7z

Запаковал в винде многотомный архив, залил на сервер, попробовал раскаковать командой:

```
7z x arch.7z.001
```

Получил:

```
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive


ERRORS:
Headers Error
WARNINGS:
There are data after the end of archive
```

Comment: У вас как минимум многотомный архив. Все тома на сервере присутствуют?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/134227/416190

Comment: да все тома на сервере, объединил как сказано по ссылке, добавив -tsplit , но после этого он все еще не распаковывается, выдает тоже самое

Comment: пытаюсь распаковывать уже объединенный архив командой 7z x arch.7z  , получаю:Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive There are data after the end of archive

Can't open as archive: 1

Comment: думал архивы битые, перепаковал и перезалил, не помогло , та же ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Установи пакет

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

И пробуй тоже самое, что ты делаешь.

```
7z x arch.7z.001
```

Comment: У меня именно этот пакет и установлен

Comment: Экспериментировал с размерами томов: 100,150,200,250,300М. Менял способ сжатия с lzma2 на lzma1, упаковывал перед сжатием в tar. Но все время ода и та же ошибка: Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive. ERRORS:
Headers Error.
WARNINGS:
There are data after the end of archive. Мучаюсь уже третий день , перебираю все возможные настройки. Попробовал залить маленький архив разрезанный - никаких ошибок. Пробовал упаковать не в 7z , а в XZ , метод сжатия оставил LZMA2, не помогло.

Comment: То есть с маленьким архивом проблем нет , а с большим есть. Тогда я попробовал разбить свой огромный архив на тома по 3мб (вышло 300 частей), залил, в итоге опять та же самая ошибка

Comment: Чем упаковываешь? Какая версия?

Comment: 7z официальная последняя версия для windows

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась так: сверил размеры всех закачанных на сервер частей архива с частями на компе и перезалил те части размер которых не совпадал. В итоге архив распаковался.

PS. Другая проблема в том, что каждый раз размер какого нибудь куска не совпадает и приходиться перезакачивать его заново.

Comment: Какие у вас были причины изменения размеров файлов при закачке?

Comment: Решение хреновое, т.к сейчас залил еще один разрезанный архив и вижу что  размер четырех залитых на сервер кусков архива из шести, отличается от размера этих же кусков на мое компе, то есть нужно перезаливать 4 куска. Причину почему при закачке меняется размер не знаю.

Comment: Вот хорошо бы с этой причиной и разобраться. А этот вопрос удалить, т.к. он некорректен (порожден другой проблемой)